# How to filter epoll events?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, epoll

Lets say I am listening at multiple network ports:
  80 with TCP
  81-250 with UDP

This requires multiple different ways of handling inputs.
- New socket at port 80 ( add new file descriptor to epoll list )
- Read from client socket at port 80
- Read from any of the other 170 UDP ports

This are quite a lot different handles, while I would like to use epoll to only react to the ones being updated.
Is there any way epoll events can be filtered, so every event gets its needed handle, without looping through all file descriptors?

Thanks in advance,
Sinned

Example code:

```
int epfd = epoll_create( 10 );

int tcpFd = createTCPSocket( 80 );
registerListenEvent( epfd, tcpFd );

int udpFds[ 170 ];
for ( int i = 0; i < 170; i++ ) {
  udpSockets[ i ] = createUdpSocket( 81 + i );
  registerUdpPacketEvent( epfd, udpFds[ i ] );
}

int tcpClientFds[ 256 ];
int tcpClientId = 0;

struct epoll_event events[ 64 ];

while ( 1 ) {
  int nfds = epoll_wait( epfd, events, 64, -1 );
  for ( int i = 0; i < nfds; i++ ) {
    struct epoll_event event = events[ i ];
    int fd = event.data.fd;

    // This kind of filtering can take quite a while
    if ( fd == tcpFd ) {
      int acceptedFd = accept( tcpFd );
      registerTcpClientEvent( epfd, acceptedFd );
      tcpClientFds[ tcpClientId++ ] = acceptedFd;
    } else {
      for ( int i = 0; i < 170; i++ )
        if ( udpFds[ i ] == fd ) {
          handleUdpMessage( fd );
          return;
        }
     for ( int i = 0; i < tcpClientId; i++ ) {
       if ( tcpClientFds[ i ] == fd ) {
         handleTcpMessage( fd );
         return;
       }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

You can imagine going through 170 - 426 loops for every event can be quite costly.
I hoped the event could be identified without this.
Is this possible?

Comment: What do mean by _being updated_? You want to select events from a subset of your descriptors?

Answer (score 2):

`epoll()` tells you the exact file descriptor(s) that triggered the event(s). You don't have to hunt for them. [Read the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) for an example.  `epoll_wait()` gives you an array of `epoll_event` structs, one for each satisfied file descriptor.  The `epoll_event` struct has an `fd` member.  You would register your individual sockets for `EPOLLIN` events, and then each time `epoll_wait()` reports satisfied events, you would read from just the reported sockets as needed.

Comment: That way I still have to identify what those file descriptors are. I want to easily find out whether they're TCP-listen, TCP-read or UDP. I added some sample code to the post to make it more clear.

Comment: @Dennis The `events` member tells you which events happened on that FD. What's your question?

Comment: A TCP fd needs to be read with `read`, while a UDP fd needs to be read with `recvfrom`. There is no way to know whether it's a TCP or UDP socket based on the epoll result. Or is there?

Comment: You can use `getsockopt(SO_TYPE)` to differentiate between a TCP and UDP socket. But for so any sockets, you might consider creating a few worker threads. One that just services TCP listener sockets. One that services just TCP reader sockets. One that services just UDP sockets. That will simplify your lookup code.

Comment: Or you can include your own user-defined data when registering the sockets with `epoll_ctl()`. The same data will be reported by `epoll_wait()`. So you can use your own custom identifiers to know which sockets are TCP vs UDP.

Comment: @Dennis You can use 'recv()' on both, actually, and possibly  'recvfrom()' as well.

Comment: The only difference between `recv()` and `recvfrom()` is that `recv()` does not report the sender IP:port. You don't need that in TCP (you can use `getpeername()` instead), but you almost always need it in UDP. So you don't need `recvfrom()` in TCP or `recv()` in UDP in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Like 'remy' mentioned create your own structure per socket and add it to event. When event triggered first refer your structure and start handling.

```
    struct epoll_event event = {0, {NULL, 0, 0, 0}};
    int s = 0;

    event.data.fd = tp->task_socket;
    event.data->ptr = tp;
    event.events = EPOLLOUT;

    assert(efd);

    s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, tp->task_socket, &event);
```

handling part:

case EPOLLOUT:
        tp = (task *)ev->data->ptr;

This tp should tell all about your sockets and handling function..